# How to implement a generic interface that extends another generic interface in Java?

Tags: java, class, generics, design-patterns, interface

I am new to Java and working on implementing generic interfaces and that's where I'd love some help.

I want to implement a generic interface in Java that extends another interface. This is how the current interface structure looks like -

```
interface ItemsProviderInterface<ExtReq, ExtRes> 
extends GenericItemProviderInterface<ItemRequest, ExtReq, ExtRes, ItemResponse> {}


interface GenericItemProviderInterface<Req, ExtReq, ExtRes, Res>{
    ExtReq convertInput(Req req)
    Res convertResponse(ExtRes res)
    ExtRes request(ExtReq req)
}
```

I want to implement the `ItemsProviderInterface` interface and provide a definition for `convertInput(), convertResponse(), request()` methods.

Maybe something like -

```
class itemsProvider<> implements ItemsProviderInterface<>
```

I am not sure which generic type to define the class with.. the ones corresponding to ItemsProviderInterface or GenericItemProviderInterface. I read up a lot of blog posts and searched StackOverflow for a similar question but couldn't find one. Any help is HUGELY appreciated.

Comment: You are implementing `ItemsProviderInterface` so that interface is the one who's generic type you care about. Now what types `ExtReq` and `ExtRes` should be is something we cannot tell you as that entirely depends on what you want your code to do. It could either make sense to just declare your itemsProvider as generic as well `class itemsProvider<ExtReq, ExtRes> implements ItemsProviderInterface<ExtReq, ExtRes>` or non generic and fixed to a specific type.`class itemsProvider implements ItemsProviderInterface<SomeType, AnotherType>` where `SomeType` is an actual type like String for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's worth inspecting which identifier means what in this case. Let's look at the base interface first `GenericItemProviderInterface<Req, ExtReq, ExtRes, Res>`.

Here all 4 type parameters `Req`, `ExtReq`, `ExtRes` and `Res` are type parameters. That's important to remember, because they are not themselves types!

Then let's look at the definition of the derived interface: `ItemsProviderInterface<ExtReq, ExtRes>` only has 2 type parameters: `ExtReq` and `ExtRes`. Note that despite the identical names, those don't inherently have anything to do with the ones on the base interface. That connection comes now:

```
interface ItemsProviderInterface<ExtReq, ExtRes> 
extends GenericItemProviderInterface<ItemRequest, ExtReq, ExtRes, ItemResponse>
```

This means that an `ItemsProviderInterface` **is-a** `GenericProviderInterface` with the 4 type parameters set like this:

- `Req` of `GenericItemProviderInterface` is set to the actual type (class or interface) `ItemRequest`.
- `ExtReq` of `GenericItemProviderInterface` is set to the type parameter `ExtReq` of `ItemsProviderItnerface`
- `ExtRes` of `GenericItemProviderInterface` is set ot the type parameter `ExtRes` of `ItemsProviderInterface`
- `Res` of `GenericItemProviderInterface` is set to the actual type `ItemResponse`.

So 2 of the 4 type parameters of the base-class are "fixed" to a specific type and the remaining two are left variable.

If you now implement `ItemProviderInterface` you could *either* also have 2 type parameters and route them to `ExtReq`/`ExtRes` *or* fix them to specific classes (or do 1-and-1, but that's probably not useful for this specific example.

So *either*

```
class MyItemProvider<ExtReq, ExtRes>
    implements ItemProviderInterface<ExtReq, ExtRes> {...}
```

*or*

```
class MySpecificItemProvider
    implements ItemProviderInterface<MySpecificExtReq, MySpecificExtRes> {...}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your use case, the class **itemsProvider** is implementing **ItemsProviderInterface**, so the class should only be dealing with the generic type of what the implementing interface holds.

In this class you want to implement the methods, you can go about in two ways. Since you said you want to provide an implementation of the methods, I am going by the thought that you would be needing specific return types on the methods. In that case, you could go about and do this

```
public class itemsProvider<String, Integer> implements ItemsProviderInterface<String, Integer> {
```

Here, I took for example that ExtReq and ExtRes are String and Integer type respectively during invocation

Answer (score 0):

> I am not sure which generic type to define the class with.. the ones corresponding to ItemsProviderInterface or GenericItemProviderInterface.

Class `ItemsProvider` directly implements `ItemsProviderInterface`, so it must specify values for the parameters defined by that interface.  It is the responsibility of that interface (which it faithfully discharges) to defines the parameters applicable to its extension of `GenericItemProviderInterface`.

This is perhaps a bit obscure semantically, but it is unmistakable syntactically, especially in a case like this where the sub- and super-interfaces have different numbers of parameters.  The parameter values you put between the angle brackets in this `implements` clause ...

> ```
> implements ItemsProviderInterface<>
> ```

... are parameters for the interface named in the clause.  And if you try to provide the wrong number of them then the compiler will reject your code.